# Why doesn't Navigation.PopAsync() trigger the OnAppearing method of the underlying page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin Forms `Application` has a `MainPage` set to

```
new NavigationPage(new CarsMasterDetailPage())
```

where `CarsMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage`.

In `CarsMasterDetailPage` constructor, I set the `Master` property to `new CarsMasterPage()` and the `Detail` property to `new CarsDetailPage()`. Both `CarsMasterPage` and `CarsDetailPage` extend `ContentPage`.

The master page contains a list of cars and a button which has an event handler that does:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new AddCar());
```

The `AddCar` page has a button with an event handler that does:

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

When I first run the app, the `OnAppearing` method of the master page is called. The first time the navigation pops back to the master page, `OnAppearing` is called again. Subsequent navigation pushes and pops don't, though.

I can get around it by adding a delegate on the master page that the add car page calls when it's done, but that feels hacky since there are page events to handle this. Does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: Send a custom message or create a custom event handler to do your job after any page pops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I did it like this and everything works fine:
My MainPage:

```
MainPage = new MasterDetailPage {
                Master = new MasterDetailPage1Master(),
                Detail = new MyNavigationPage(new MainPageLinearList(appType))
            };
```

So the key point was to use NavigationPage in a DetailPage. After that everything works fine.

Comment: This eventually got me there, thanks. I had to remove the `NavigationPage` wrapping the `MasterDetailPage` and then wrap both Master and Detail pages in a `NavigationPage`.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the [`NavigationPage.Popped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.popped?view=xamarin-forms) event:

```
navigationPage.Popped += OnPopped;

...

void OnPopped(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var currentPage = (sender as NavigationPage).CurrentPage;
    var removedPage = e.Page;
    ...
}
```